# Option 'complefunc' not set

Tags: vim, autocomplete, eclim

I'm starting to use vim in working with java and I want auto complete function eclim does. But while using Ctrl+X then Ctrl + U a message on status bar appear that

> Option 'completefunc' not set

What are the steps in to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you install it?  Did you read the instructions at http://eclim.org/install.html?

Comment: Try :set complefunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Eclim's FAQ: http://eclim.org/faq.html#i-m-editing-a-java-python-php-etc-file-and-code-completion-doesn-t-work

> This usually indicates that you don’t have file type plugins enabled
>   in vim. To check you can run:
>
> `:EclimValidate`
>
> If it complains about filetype plugin support not being found, then
>   follow its directions on adding the following to your vimrc:
>
> `filetype plugin indent on`

From my personal experience, this error happens when you are trying to edit a file that is not a known part of any known project, or filetype of which isn't known.